# Weather Application - Reavling Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, datetime, revealing-module-pattern

I'm trying to practice and learn design patterns, and I decided to create a weather app using the revealing module pattern. How can I improve on this, and what mistakes did I make?

## Main.js

```
import '../styles/main.scss';
import {weatherModule} from './weather';
import {dateModule} from './date';


dateModule.getCurrentDate();
weatherModule.render();
```

## Weather.js

```
let weatherModule = (function() {

  let APPID = '09ca7c40368550f8e6a0a2851a56acd5';
  let dailyUrl = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?';
  let weatherTemperature;
  let weatherLocation;
  let weatherDescription;

  function getPositionByGeolocation(lat, lon) {
    dailyUrl += 'lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + '&APPID=' + APPID + '&units=metric';
    sendRequest(dailyUrl);
  }


  function sendRequest(url) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        let dailyWeather = {};
        dailyWeather.location = data.name;
        dailyWeather.temp = data.main.temp + ' &deg;C';
        dailyWeather.desc = data.weather[0].description;
        update(dailyWeather);
      }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.timeout = 5000;
    xhr.ontimeout = () => {
      let timeOutText = 'Request timed out';
      console.log('Current weather request timed out');
      document.getElementById('text--timeout').style = 'display: block';
      weatherLocation.innerHTML = timeOutText;
      weatherTemperature.innerHTML = timeOutText;
      weatherDescription.innerHTML = timeOutText;
    }
    xhr.send();
  }

  function update(dailyWeather) {
    weatherLocation.innerHTML = dailyWeather.location;
    weatherTemperature.innerHTML = dailyWeather.temp;
    weatherDescription.innerHTML = dailyWeather.desc;
  }

  function render() {
    window.onload = () => {
      weatherLocation = document.getElementById('weather-location');
      weatherTemperature = document.getElementById('weather-temperature');
      weatherDescription = document.getElementById('weather-description');

      if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
        function getPosition(position) {
          getPositionByGeolocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
          document.getElementById('text--warning').style = 'display: hidden';
        }
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);
      }
      let geoLocationWarningText = "Your browser does not support geolocation. Pleae enable geolocation in your browser.";
      let geoLocationWarning = document.getElementById('text--warning');
      geoLocationWarning.innerHTML = geoLocationWarningText;
      document.getElementById('text--warning').style = 'display: block';
    }

  }

  return {
    render: render,
    sendRequest: sendRequest
  }

})();

export {weatherModule};
```

## Date.js

```
let dateModule = (function() {

  let getCurrentDate = function() {

    let daysOfWeek = {
      0: 'Sunday',
      1: 'Monday',
      2: 'Tuesday',
      3: 'Wednesday',
      4: 'Thursday',
      5: 'Friday',
      6: 'Saturday'
    };

    let monthsInYear = {
      0: 'January',
      1: 'February',
      2: 'March',
      3: 'April',
      4: 'May',
      5: 'June',
      6: 'July',
      7: 'August',
      8: 'September',
      9: 'October',
      10: 'November',
      11: 'December'
    }
    let date = new Date();
    let dayOfWeek = date.getDay();
    let dayOfMonth = date.getDate();
    let month = date.getMonth();
    let year = date.getFullYear();

    let day = daysOfWeek[dayOfWeek] + ' ' + dayOfMonth + ' ' + monthsInYear[month] + ' ' + year;
    document.getElementById('current-date').innerHTML = day;

  }
  return {
    getCurrentDate: getCurrentDate
  }

})();

export {dateModule};
```

Comment: "Your browser does not support geolocation. Pleae enable geolocation in your browser." If it's not supported, how can I enable it? You need to reword this message.